# Orchestration API - (POST And Get API) using spring boot

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have to construct Orchestration API which calls internally GET API and the response body of GET call should be passed has the request body of POST API automatically using java Spring boot
first :-> get call: /students/{id}/information and response will be
{
  "id": "123",
  "name": "abc",
  "marks": 80
}
Now the above output of get response should be passed as request body for post call. instead of doing manual copying get response and pasting as request body to post call.
it should be done automatically
please post your idea's
thanks

Comment: So what is you question?

Comment: How to construct such type of API? where Post request body should be response body of GET API passed.